# converting sql command query to stored procedure in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

Hello guys I have a problem with my current system.

things are working fine using this query in my forms.

```
Private Sub btnsearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click





    'Dim connstr As String = "server=midtelephone\sqlexpress; database=testdb; user= sa; password=sa;"
    Dim cmdconn2 = New SqlConnection
    cmdconn2 = New SqlConnection
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmdconn2.ConnectionString = sqlstr
    cmd.Connection = cmdconn2
    cmdconn2.Open()


    If CheckForText1() = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot search with an empty value!")
        frmVetsearch.Dispose()
        Exit Sub
    Else

        cmd.CommandText = "select a.lname, a.fname, a.mi, a.vdms_no, b.lname, b.fname, b.mi, b.CLAIM_NO, c.ADDRESS1, c.ADDRESS2, c.ADDRESS3, c.sex, c.SCHOOL, c.C_YEAR, c.COURSE," & _
                          "c.telephone_no, c.mobile_no, c.email_add, c.EFFECTIVITY_DATE, c.SCC_NO, c.MLIST_NO, c.CATEGORY, c.DATE_FILED, c.relation_to_veteran, c.ENTITLEMENT_AWARD," & _
                          "c.REMARKS, c.UPDATED_BY, c.D_UPDATED from carlos.claims_veteran a left join carlos.claims_waivee b on a.vdms_no = b.vdms_no left join tobee.EBD_SCHBILLS c " & _
                          "on b.claim_no = c.CLAIM_NO where a.lname like '" + txtLname.Text + "%' and a.fname like '%" + txtFname.Text + "%' and a.mi like '%" + txtMi.Text + "%' " & _
                          "and a.VDMS_no like '" + txtVDMSNo.Text + "%'"


        btnsearch.Enabled = False
        btnSearchStud.Enabled = False


        frmVetsearch.ShowDialog()
        cmdconn.Close()

    End If

End Sub
```

now, i'm trying to improve my system by transferring this query into a stored procedure.
is there any possibility that i could that thing. if there is could you pls provide me a guide or a solution? Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: First step: use **parametrized queries** instead of concatenating together your SQL! This will protect your app from SQL injection attacks, and improve your performance. Then: what benefit do you expect from turning this into a stored procedure? A properly parametrized query is just as good, just as fast as a stored procedure.... what are you trying to achieve by converting to a stored procedure?

Comment: well, as you know stored proc. is apart from the forms.. wherein. u can edit the query anytime u want without recompiling the form.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to use your Sql Server Management Studio or your Server Explorer windows in Visual Studio to [create the stored procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectClaims
(
     @fname nvarchar(max), 
     @lname nvarchar(max), 
     @mi nvarchar(max), 
     @vdms nvarchar(max)
)
as

select 
    a.lname, a.fname, a.mi, a.vdms_no, b.lname, b.fname, b.mi, b.CLAIM_NO, 
    c.ADDRESS1, c.ADDRESS2, c.ADDRESS3, c.sex, c.SCHOOL, c.C_YEAR, c.COURSE,
    c.telephone_no, c.mobile_no, c.email_add, c.EFFECTIVITY_DATE, c.SCC_NO, c.MLIST_NO, 
    c.CATEGORY, c.DATE_FILED, c.relation_to_veteran, c.ENTITLEMENT_AWARD,
    c.REMARKS, c.UPDATED_BY, c.D_UPDATED 
from carlos.claims_veteran a left join carlos.claims_waivee b on a.vdms_no = b.vdms_no 
                             left join tobee.EBD_SCHBILLS c On b.claim_no = c.CLAIM_NO 
where a.lname like @lname and a.fname like @fname and a.mi like @mi and a.VDMS_no like @vdms
```

As you can see, this sp receives 4 parameters, all of type `nvarchar` and I have set their size to the max possible value (you should fine tune this value to the effective size of your relative fields)

Then in VB.NET you call this SP with this code

```
If CheckForText1() = False Then
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot search with an empty value!")
    frmVetsearch.Dispose()
    Exit Sub
Else
    Using cmdconn2 = New SqlConnection(sqlstr)
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SelectClaims", cmdconn2)
        cmdconn2.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLname.Text & "%")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", "%" & txtFname.Text & "%"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mi", "%" & txtMi.Text & "%"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vdms", txtVDMSNo.Text & "%"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        .... you are missing the code that read back your values
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
             .......
        End Using

    End Using
    End Using
End If
```

The important things here are

- The CommandType is set to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` to allow
  proper handling of the CommandText set to the name of a stored
  procedure instead of a sql statement.
- Every value that need to be passed to the stored procedure is added
  to the Parameters collection of the SqlCommand using AddWithValue.
  However, if you really need to get the maximum performance possible
  you should build every parameter specifying its size and type
- Every disposable object (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader)
  are enclosed in a using statement that will ensure proper closing and
  disposing also in case of exceptions

I wish however warn you in using this approach. In a select like this, using a stored procedure, don't give a clear advantage against a proper parameterized query. From my point of view, I have found  that using and maintaining a large number of stored procedures could easily become a real maintenance nightmare.

Suppose, for example, that a new version of your program needs to retrieve a new field.
Now you need to update both your code and your stored procedure. And don't forget that in some environments you need to request the help of a dedicated person ( A DBA) just to make any changes to the a database in production.